# How to achieve exact radio button style design?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, styling

I am sharing an image of button can some one help with the html css to achieve exact design.
[Normal state of radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJhaL.jpg)

[On hover style or Checked state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfroS.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to tackle this at all? If so, please share your attempts

Answer (score 0):

html code:

```html
<div class="radio-button">
    <input class="radio-button__input" type="radio" name="" id="btn">
    <label class="radio-button__label" for="btn">Text here</label>
</div>
```

css code:

```css
.radio-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.radio-button__input{
    display: none;
}
.radio-button__label{
    border: .1em solid gray;
    font-size: 48px;
    padding: .5em;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
.radio-button__input:hover + .radio-button__label, .radio-button__input:checked + .radio-button__label{
    background-color: mediumvioletred;
}
```

styling on .radio-button is only to center it so you can delete it if you need to
if you want the transition to be smooth just add `transition` on `.radio-button__label`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need to make group of radio button in which only one can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.radio input {
  display: none;
}
.radio-box {
  padding: 15px 30px 12px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #868aa8;
  border: 2px solid #868aa8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 34px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.radio input:checked + .radio-box,
.radio-box:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ea0b5b;
  border-color: #ea0b5b;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="time">
  <span class="radio-box">5:30 PM</span>
</label>
```